# install java on mac os x

Tags: java, macos

i have macbook pro and have set java and java home. now it says that your JAVA_HOME is not set correctly. i want to completely remove java and install it again. how can i do this?
Thanks.

Comment: You can set `JAVA_HOME` to `/Library/Java/Home`

Comment: Assuming you have a stock mac os x install wouldn't it be easier to fix your java_home instead?

Comment: try echo $PATH and check that what it will show

Comment: The current version of Mac OS X comes with Java preinstalled. Is there any reason why you're it installing it yourself?

Comment: @Erik : i tried that but couldn't get a good result. exactly i want to change my JAVA_HOME and i tried to do so, but it doesn't get changed. i didn't know what else i could do but to reinstall java on my mac

Answer (score 3):

Put `export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)` in your .profile and java_home will be set correctly.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a Java based tool like ant or maven not being able to locate the JDK.

It does not mean you have to reinstall Java (which by the way is pretty hard for OS X) but that you should set your environment variables properly.

For a one shot, just set

```
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/Home
```

in your shell, and then run ant or maven in your shell.

Comment: i did that. and maven could locate it. but when i quit terminal and run it again maven gets confused. so i put the following in my .profile :

Comment: file:                                                              "export JAVA_HOME=/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.frameworks/Version/1.6.0_22/HOME" but again when i quit terminal and run it again and type " echo $JAVA_HOME " it shows the wrong java home and maven gets confused again. i can't figure out what is wrong.

Comment: Then it is the wrong configuration file.  Use  `.bashrc` instead.